# How to update waitForDuration constant?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

I have a flashing light that uses a SKAction sequence that hides and unhides a circle node. I want to be able to change the intervals at which it flashes based on two buttons. I declared a variable stdTime and I change it in the touchesBegan method but it's not working. What am I missing?

my didMoveToView:

```
let blink = SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.waitForDuration(stdTime),
        SKAction.hide(),
        SKAction.waitForDuration(stdTime),
        SKAction.unhide()])

    let blinkForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(blink)

    metronome!.runAction(blinkForever)
```

and my touchesBegan:

```
if upArrow!.containsPoint(location) {
            stdTime = stdTime + 0.1
            println("here: \(stdTime)")
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change SKAction which is running forever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995855/how-to-change-skaction-which-is-running-forever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

waitForDuration takes in a NSTimeInterval and not a variable. So it takes whatever time that variable was set to at creation and does not refer back to the variable you used.

Depending on the result you are looking for this might help.

```
func startBlink(){
    let blink = SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.waitForDuration(stdTime),
        SKAction.hide(),
        SKAction.waitForDuration(stdTime),
        SKAction.unhide()])

    let blinkForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(blink)

    metronome!.removeActionForKey("blink")

    metronome!.runAction(blinkForever, withKey: "blink")
}


if upArrow!.containsPoint(location) {
    stdTime = stdTime + 0.1
    startBlink()
    println("here: \(stdTime)")
}
```

Another option without interrupting the sequence is to do something like this

```
func startBlink(){

    let blink = SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.waitForDuration(stdTime),
        SKAction.hide(),
        SKAction.waitForDuration(stdTime),
        SKAction.unhide(),
        SKAction.runBlock( {
            self.startBlink()
        })])

    metronome?.runAction(blink, withKey: "blink")
}


if upArrow!.containsPoint(location) {
        stdTime = stdTime + 0.1
        println("here: \(stdTime)")
}
```

And recursively call the method on your own. That way each time it hits the end it will take the updated stdTime.